# AWS RedShift auto converting CTE into Subquery

Tags: amazon-redshift, common-table-expression

I've got a strange issue. I got an SQL View written using CTE. When I create the View in AWS RedShift using Aginity Workbench or SQL Workbench - it automatically converts the CTE into Subqueries and saves the DDL.

I would like to retain the CTE version of the SQL in the DDL.

Why would RedShift do this and how do I avoid it?

Thanks.

Comment: Please post the example code, or a slimmed down reproducible version of the issue. Thanks. That said, it's likely your CTE is recursive, since RedShift is based on PostgreSql but does not support the recursive CTE functionality. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/c_unsupported-postgresql-features.html

Comment: Agree with the request for example SQL, however this is issue is **highly** unlikely to be related to recursion since the OP states that the view is being created successfully.

Comment: @JoeHarris Why is that?  I'm not an expert in the tools the OP mentions, but to me it sounds like the tools are doing the magic, rather than RedShift

Comment: Redshift supports CTEs just find, even complex nested CTEs. Recursive CTEs are the only unsupported pattern.

Comment: I was able to reproduce the same behavior. Created a view with a CTE, view definition has a subquery